# File Input cuts off first word

Tags: c++, file-processing

I am writing a program that should be able to take input, create a file, and store that information. I have successfully done that part. The program should also be able to print a previous file to the screen. The problem I get is that it cuts off the first word on the first line of the file call. For example, I would click `n` and input a previous text file such as `test.txt` and it would print the following:

```
Kennedy
CSC 201
Computer Science
Mondays and Wednesdays
Scott Davis
```

when it should print:

```
John Kennedy
CSC 201
Computer Science
Mondays and Wednesdays
Scott Davis
```

What did I do wrong for file printing?

```
 #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;
    string inFile, outFile, fullName, fileName;
    string courseCode, courseName, courseProfessor, courseHours;
    char answer;
    int counter = 0;
    int courses;

    cout << "Are you creating a new file? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 'n')
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of your file." << endl;
        cin >> inFile;
        cin.ignore (200, '\n');
        inData.open(inFile.c_str());
        inData >> fileName;
        cout << inData.rdbuf();
    }
    else if(answer == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of your file." << endl;
        cin >> outFile;
        cin.ignore (200, '\n');
        outData.open(outFile.c_str());
        cout << "What is your full name?" << endl;
        getline(cin, fullName);
        outData << fullName << endl;
        outData << endl;
        cout << "How many courses are you taking?" << endl;
        cin >> courses;
        while(courses > counter)
        {
            cin.ignore (200, '\n');
            cout << "What is the code for your class?" << endl;
            getline(cin, courseCode);
            outData << courseCode << endl;
            cout << "What is the name of the course?" << endl;
            getline(cin, courseName);
            outData << courseName << endl;
            cout << "What days and time periods do you take this course?" << endl;
            getline(cin, courseHours);
            outData << courseHours << endl;
            cout << "What is the name of your professor?" << endl;
            getline(cin, courseProfessor);
            outData << courseProfessor << endl;
            outData << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    inData.close();
    outData.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `inData >> fileName;` after `inData.open(inFile.c_str());`

It will read the first word into fileName and move the current file position.

Comment: ...that was embarrassingly easy to fix. I simply deleted that portion of the code since it's redundant and unnecessary. Thanks. I missed that. Since the file name is already stated (because it's a previous file) there is no reason to restate the file name....derp. I appreciate it!